# Scope in rails to refine search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to refine my article and giving my user flexibility to decide what they want to view.

Here the models with relationship

```
  Article
    has_many :tags, through: :articletags
  ArticleTags
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :tags
  Tags
    has_many :article, through: articletags
```

Now the idea is the use would go in article and on the side see the tags.title which then give refresh the pages with Article where tags = "world". Now i am trying to do this with scope but i am not to sure how to do it. Here my scope in my model

```
scope :by_tags, where(title => ?, "world news")
```

Here how i call it

```
<%= link_to (tag.title), articles_path(:scope => "test") %>
```

But obviously it doesn't work how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View**

```
<%= link_to (tag.title), articles_path(:scope => tag.title) %>
```

**Model(Article)**

```
def self.by_tags(tag)
  joins(:tags).where('tags.title = ?', tag)
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @articles = Article.by_tags(params[:scope])
end
```